# Recursive function in javascript using graphology library to return parent nodes of a selected node

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, iteration, graph-theory

I am using graphology which is a library that provides a graph object made of nodes and edges.
I have a structure similar to the one in the image attached.

[image: Network structure image]

Each edge has a direction associated with it.
I would like to create a function (likely recursive) that will return the parents of a node selected.
Eg. `parentsOfFunction(6)` should return

```
[
  [4,1],
  [5,
      [2,3],
  ]
]
```

Where each time there is a branching of edges from a node, a new child element is made in the array.
I believe this to be the best way to store the results to then be iterated over later, but am happy to change the structure so long as the structure can be inferred.
Currently my function only returns `[4,5]` which are the first level of parents of `6`.
The `console.log` values are correct but I am unable to work out how to store this in a variable.
Any help appreciated, TIA.

***EDIT:
I have actually worked out a function for this? Would this be a suitable/efficient way of doing the above? Thanks again.***

[Updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-goldwasser-l56y23)

Code:

```js
import Graph from "graphology";
const graph = new Graph({
  multi: false,
  allowSelfLoops: false,
  type: "directed"
});

graph.addNode("1");
graph.addNode("2");
graph.addNode("3");
graph.addNode("4");
graph.addNode("5");
graph.addNode("6");

graph.addEdge("1", "4", { name: "a" });
graph.addEdge("2", "5", { name: "b" });
graph.addEdge("3", "5", { name: "c" });
graph.addEdge("4", "6", { name: "d" });
graph.addEdge("5", "6", { name: "e" });

let parents = [];

function getNodes(node) {
  return graph.inboundNeighbors(node);
}

function recursive(startingNode) {
  let list = getNodes(startingNode);
  if (list.length < 0) {
    parents[0] = list;
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      parents[i] = [list[i], getNodes(list[i])];
    }
  }
}
recursive(6);
console.log(parents);
```

Comment: `if (list.length < 0)` will never hold, so you can just omit it, and `parent` must not be a global variable but created inside the function (for each function call), but otherwise this is looking fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `recursive` function isn't actually recursive, so your code doesn't work. It just produces two-level deep output that happens to look fairly OK-ish (but not quite) on the example test. Try other test cases.

Also, the expected output is a very unusual data structure since it mixes types. This is an antipattern that you should avoid if possible. It also omits the root, which makes the recursive logic a bit awkward to write. I used an extra inner function to strip off the root.

Here's one approach that uses a mixed-type return value and a test to determine how many parents we have. The logic for a given call is as follows:

- If this node has no parents, it's a leaf node. Return it directly, without an array wrapper.
- If this node has one parent, it should be returned in an array directly alongside its parent subtree.
- If this node has multiple parents, it should be returned in an array with its parents' subtrees in a subarray.

```js
const buildTreeFromParents = (graph, start) => {
  const recurse = start => {
    const parents = graph.inboundNeighbors(start);

    if (parents.length === 0) {
      return start;
    }
    else if (parents.length === 1) {
      return [start, recurse(parents[0])];
    }

    return [start, parents.map(recurse)];
  };

  return graph.inboundNeighbors(start).map(recurse);
};

const graph = new graphology.Graph({
  multi: false,
  allowSelfLoops: false,
  type: "directed"
});
graph.addNode(1);
graph.addNode(2);
graph.addNode(3);
graph.addNode(4);
graph.addNode(5);
graph.addNode(6);
graph.addEdge(1, 4, {name: "a"});
graph.addEdge(2, 5, {name: "b"});
graph.addEdge(3, 5, {name: "c"});
graph.addEdge(4, 6, {name: "d"});
graph.addEdge(5, 6, {name: "e"});
console.log(buildTreeFromParents(graph, 6));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphology/0.21.0/graphology.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Try to avoid global variables when writing functions, which should be purely self-contained to avoid bugs and confusing state modification and dependencies.

---

Based on the comments, here's the code that addresses a couple of the awkward issues mentioned above. It's still a mixed-type structure, but at least the root is included and the parent nesting makes more sense as no special condition is taken when there's only one parent.

```js
const buildTreeFromParents = (graph, start) => {
  const parents = graph.inboundNeighbors(start);

  if (parents.length === 0) {
    return start;
  }

  return [start, parents.map(e => buildTreeFromParents(graph, e))];
};

const graph = new graphology.Graph({
  multi: false,
  allowSelfLoops: false,
  type: "directed"
});
graph.addNode(1);
graph.addNode(2);
graph.addNode(3);
graph.addNode(4);
graph.addNode(5);
graph.addNode(6);
graph.addEdge(1, 4, {name: "a"});
graph.addEdge(2, 5, {name: "b"});
graph.addEdge(3, 5, {name: "c"});
graph.addEdge(4, 6, {name: "d"});
graph.addEdge(5, 6, {name: "e"});
console.log(buildTreeFromParents(graph, 6));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphology/0.21.0/graphology.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I tried my code with a larger tree and it's limited to only two levels down. I have two questions if that is okay, firstly, can I remove the else statement so that if there are no parents it lists the parents in an array and if there is a parent a level up it adds it as a new sub array as when I iterate over the list I need to know how many levels deep it is. Secondly, I omitted the root in my code and added it in after checking the parents as I couldn't figure it. How would I edit your code to keep the root e.g. of `6` in the array at the top level? Thanks again

Comment: Not sure I understand the first requirement, but the second one is easy: just remove the `const recurse = start => {` and `return graph.inboundNeighbors(start).map(recurse);` lines and change any `recurse` calls to `buildTreeFromParents`, passing the graph in as the first parameter. Effectively, we're getting rid of the inner function. If your new set of requirements are substantially different, please ask a new question to avoid moving the goalpost too much from the original question.

Comment: I see, so I mean to say it should be such that a new subarray is created each time you go "up" one level, e.g. from 4->1 but for 2 and 3 they should be within the same array as they are on the same horizontal plane. Am I explaining it better?

Comment: OK, then get rid of the second condition that treats single parent subtrees as flat.

Comment: I see, thanks once again for your time! Very helpful and kind in your explanation to a hobbyist :)